# Count observations for each group within dynamic date-time range

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

The data is below:

```
Customer_ID    Trans_ID    Trans_DateTime
  A             1            2014-10-01 10:02:09
  A             2            2014-10-01 16:20:09
  B             3            2014-10-01 12:05:20
  B             4            2014-10-01 17:05:20
  A             5            2014-12-01 10:02:09
  A             6            2014-12-01 10:02:50
  B             7            2014-12-01 12:05:19
  B             8            2014-12-01 12:05:21
```

**I need to count the number of transactions for each customer within the next two months after their first transaction.** I am only able to find the number of transactions for all customers for the next two months which is common to all. However, I need to make the period as dynamic (i.e, varying for each customer depending on when they did the first transaction.)

The output, given the data above, should look like the following:

```
Customer_ID  number_of_transactions
 A           2
 B           3
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you please `dput(...)` your example data? From the description of the tag [r]: *Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages ...*

Comment: Can you explain your expected output? All the transactions for each `Cust_ID` is within 3 months after their first transaction.

Comment: @RonakShah considering the transactions of A, I haven't counted the last transaction of A given in the data since it happened after "2014-12-01 10:02:09". Her first transaction is done on "2014-10-01 10:02:09" and the last observation within 3-month constraint is done on "2014-12-01 10:02:09", which is the 3 month "window" specific to A as defined in my problem.

Comment: @KumarAshutosh so I think that is 2 month window then? and what about `B` ? it has got all the transactions within the same month and in fact the same day.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for the correction...Then could you please treat the question as 2-month window based problem? Also for B, I should have made the month as 12 instead of 10 for the last two transactions. Forgive me.

Comment: @RonakShah my bad..thanks for letting me know about the protocol

Comment: @RonakShah my bad..thanks for letting me know about the protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. For each `Customer_ID` we find the `min`imum `Trans_DateTime` (1st Transaction) and add 2 months to it and `filter` all the transactions which happened in that window and `count` their occurrence.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
   group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
   mutate(Trans_DateTime = ymd_hms(Trans_DateTime)) %>%
   filter(Trans_DateTime < (min(Trans_DateTime) + months(2))) %>%
   count()


#   Customer_ID   n
#    <chr>       <int>
#1     A           2
#2     B           3
```